# Nerve, unknown subscript, Categories, Segal condition

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

What does it mean the index $(NC)_0$
in
$$\sigma_m:(NC)_m\to(NC)_1\times_{(NC)_0}...\times_{(NC)_0}(NC)_1?$$

This equation is from page xiii of Carlos Simpson's [book](https://books.google.be/books?id=d1JTtOqBU6oC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) "Homotopy Theory of Higher Categories : From Segal Categories to $n$-Categories and beyond".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It denotes a (generalized) pullback. Basically, if $C$ is a category, then $(NC)_0$ is the set of objects of $C$, $(NC)_1$ is the set of arrows, $d_0:(NC)_1\to (NC)_0$ (resp. $d_1$) is the function that assigns its domain (resp. codomain) to each arrow. Then the right-hand term is the limit of the diagram
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} & & & & & & (NC)_1 \\ & & & & & @V{d_1}VV \\& & & & (NC)_1@>{d_0}>> (NC)_0 \\ & & & & @V{d_1}VV \\ & & (NC)_1@>{d_0}>> (NC)_0 \\ & &\vdots \\ (NC)_1@>{d_0}>> (NC)_0\end{CD}$$with $m$ copies of $(NC)_1$. It is the set of $m$-tuple of arrows $(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_m)$ such that the domain of $f_i$ is the codomain of $f_{i+1}$ for all $0<i<m$.

So for example for $m=2$ you have the pullback
$$\begin{CD}(NC)_1\times_{(NC)_0}(NC)_1 @>>> (NC)_1\\
@VVV @VV{d_1}V\\
(NC)_1@>>{d_0}> (NC)_0\end{CD}$$
which is the set of pairs of arrows $(f,g)$ such that the composition $f\circ g$ can be defined.

For more information, you can check out the nLab pages of the [nerve](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve) and of the [Segal condition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Segal+condition).

Comment: Fine. But what are $d_0$ and $d_1$ here?

Comment: I believe they are "the obvious maps" from the simplicial structure of $NC$

Comment: How do I see that in the case $m=2$: [...]which is the set of pairs of arrows $(f,g)$ such that the composition $f∘g$ can be defined.

Comment: The pullback (in the category of sets) is the subset of the product consisting of $(f,g)$ such that $d_0(f)=d_1(g)$, i.e. such that the domain of $f$ is equal to the codomain of $g$. This is exactly the condition required for the composition $f\circ g$ to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

To write an object under a product usually indicates a fibre product (aka pullback) or a generalisation thereof, and here it is done multiple times with $(NC)_0$, the $0$-simplices of the simplicial object $NC$.